# Get Audio file from gallery and upload to a server

Tags: codenameone

Hi i am having issue uploading an audio file to a server
I am using the plugin `FileChooser` to get the audio file from gallery but i don't know how to send that audio file to server,

I have tried MultipartRequest but not working

can you show me with a simple example  how to do that?
thank you all

Comment: What's not working with the multipart request?